# How to display dashed lines in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this code to display a grid with dashed line. In runtime on an iphone 5 below it shows fine, but if I run the app on iphone 5s there's no grid. I tested in iPhone Simulator and on real devices and happens the same.

Here's the code:

```
if (self.dashLongitude) {
    CGFloat lengths[] = {3.0, 3.0};
    CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0.0, lengths, 2);
}

//other stuff here

CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0, nil, 0);
```

So anyone could help??

EDIT: Hey guys I solved the issue using the same code I posted here, but in a different method. So I have now two methods: one just for the drawing the grid and another on to draw the line with data and finally got everything working.

Comment: why you are setting the nil in `CGContextSetLinedash`?

Comment: Because that line dash is a grid and on top of that grid I draw a line based on values. So if I remove CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0, nil, 0); the line with data is the one that will be dashed. And what I want is a grid with dashed lines and on top of it the line with data. At runtime I get just the line with data but no grid.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine.

As I look into the code I saw you are setting the `nil` in the context. `nil` is used to remove the dashed line.

Try to use

```
CGFloat dash[] = {2.0, 2.0};
CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0.0, dash, 2);
```

where you are creating or provide stroke your line(underneath).

```
CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0, NULL, 0);
```

is used to remove that *dash* pattern.

Comment: Tried but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `nil` in `CGContextSetLineDash`, just wrap your code into `CGContextSaveGState`/`CGContextRestoreGState` to preserve context state before applying line dash:

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGFloat dash[] = {2.0, 2.0};
CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0.0, dash, 2);    

// Draw some lines here

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```